# How to draw forest plot from Dataframe (HR and CI)

Tags: r, ggplot2, cox-regression, r-forestplot

I have a data of cox regression from spss containing following columns. 
I am thinking to use this data as dataframe in R and create a forest plot out of it. How can i create a forest plot from this data in R? How to create forest plot from dataframe containing HR/OR and CIs. ?

Here is reproducable data as follows, it would be great help if you teach me how to make one. I tried but couldnt make one.

```
HR<-c(2,3,5)
ci_u<-c(1.2,1.1,1.3)
ci_l<-c(1.3,1.4,1.3)
names<-c("High","Low","medium")
datf<-data.frame(HR,ci_u,ci_l,sig,ns)
```

[image]

Comment: There are packages `forestplot` and `metaviz`. Perhaps they can help you out.

Comment: Thanks. I  edit my question and enter reproducable data. i will be greatful if you can give it a try

Comment: You need to share your data and your Cox Regression. See this page https://rdrr.io/cran/survminer/man/ggforest.html

Comment: Hi Thanks But i have mentioned that the data i have is not from R but from SPSS. I have already shared Hazard Ratios and confidence intervals in Question above. All i want to know is how to plot forest plot out of this data.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting a simple ggplot approach as it offers great control. The underlying idea is to plot HRs as points and then add CIs as error bars. I altered your dataset because

1. you did not define `sig` and `ns` variables in your data frame
2. the point estimates do not fall between upper and lower CI values. I understand that you made up these values, but I am changing since the plot wont look good as the CI lines will fall only at one side of the point.

I used the following dataframe

```
dataset <- data.frame(
study_label = c(paste(rep("Study", 4), 1:4, sep = "_")),
HR = c(.72, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4),
lci = c(.52, 1.1, 1.3, 1.2),
uci = c(.83, 1.9, 2.1, 1.5)
```

)

```
  require(ggplot2)
    ggplot(dataset, aes(y = study_label, x = HR))+
      geom_point()+ #map HRs as points on x axis and variables/study labels at y
      geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = lci, xmax = uci))+ #add CIs as error bars
      geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed")#draw a vertical line at x=1 as null for ratio estimates
```

[Please see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKOm8.png)

Comment: You can use package Meta to create forest plot.  Here is the code: `library(meta),  forest(metagen(log(hr), lower=log(ci_l), upper=log(ci_u) , studlab = dataset)` @aryh